# Firebase Storage exception and Crashlytics exception does not match?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, crashlytics

I'm using Firebase to download files on Android. Here is my code:

```
try {
    //.. Try to download file from Firebase
} catch(StorageException e) {
    if(e.getErrorCode() == StorageException.ERROR_RETRY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED) {
        //Ignore! Exception has occurred due to no Internet availability
    } else {
        //Other genuine failure, log it
       Crashlytics.logException(e);
    }
}
```

Now, this code does not send "The operation retry limit has been exceeded." exception. However, in Crashlytics I'm still able to see this exception being reported.

```
Non-fatal Exception: com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException
The operation retry limit has been exceeded.

Caused by javax.net.ssl.SSLException
Read error: ssl=0x7188e1fe08: I/O error during system call, Software caused connection abort
```

How is this possible? Am I missing anything?

Firebase version: 16.0.1

Answer (score 4):

Your post does not show the code for the file download.  I'll assume it has a completion listener on the `Task`.  Maybe the exception does not propagate out to an enclosing `try-block` and you need to handle it in the callback, as shown here:

```
storageRef.getFile(contentDir).addOnCompleteListener(
        new OnCompleteListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            ...
        } else {
            StorageException se = (StorageException) task.getException();
            if (se.getErrorCode() == StorageException.ERROR_RETRY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED) {
                // Ignore
            } else {
                Crashlytics.logException(se);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If I guessed wrong on your download code, please update your post to include it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. My code is exactly what you've shown. Still the exception is getting reported.

Comment: Hard to guess why this code doesn't work.  You'll probably need to add some log-statements to verify that you are getting into the `onComplete()` callback.  Also double check the stack trace in Crashlytics to confirm that the exception is the result of this call to `getFile()` and not some other call.

Comment: The strange part is that not all devices are failing to recognize this error code. Only for few devices I'm seeing this error.

Answer (score 2):

There's no guarantee that the StorageException's error code is being set or being set correctly in all cases for ERROR_RETRY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED errors and likely your check fails because of that. Basically, someone in Firebase code has a bug where they just fail to set the error_code correctly (or sets it to a different value) but the error message is set correctly, so when you print the error it looks like you would expect other than the error_code value.  If you can reproduce the error set a break point or add more logging of the exception values so you can see what the error_code is when the check fails. Try adding another check that parses the error message as a backup for cases where error_code is wrong.